# How fragments are implied for ICMP in scapy

Tags: python, scapy, tcpdump

Generally I can send a ICMP packet as mentioned below

```
srp(Ether(src=u'd2:ff:90:c5:1f:21', dst=u'9c:22:14:4f:6c:ac', type=2048)/IP(src=u'238.166.15.14', dst=u'70.74.2.83')/ICMP(type=8)/Raw(load='UZe5ICdH'),timeout=10,iface="ens192.50")
```

For example to send a fragmented packet can i do it as,

```
srp(fragment(Ether(src=u'd2:ff:90:c5:1f:21', dst=u'9c:22:14:4f:6c:ac', type=2048)/IP(src=u'238.166.15.14', dst=u'70.74.2.83')/ICMP(type=8)/Raw(load='UZe5ICdH'),fragsize=2),timeout=10,iface="ens192.50")
```

I got this from one of the blogs. But am not sure whether am doing it properly or not.

Comment: what does it mean 'properly'? what are the criteria for that?

Comment: I mean, sending a fragmented packet. I tried the above code but it didn't work. So wanted to know whether the code is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

`fragment()` should be used on an IP packet and return a list of fragments. You should change your code to send each fragment one by one:

```
frags = fragment(IP(src='238.166.15.14', dst='70.74.2.83')/ICMP(type=8)/Raw(load='UZe5ICdH'),fragsize=2)

l2 = Ether(src='d2:ff:90:c5:1f:21', dst='9c:22:14:4f:6c:ac', type=2048)

for f in frags:
 srp(l2/f, timeout=10,iface="ens192.50")
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe helpful for someone looking this topic, this code snippet given in question work fine.

```
srp(fragment(Ether(src=u'60:36:dd:3f:5f:c5', dst=u'7c:c3:85:30:8c:24', type=2048)/IP(src=u'192.168.18.24', dst=u'192.168.18.1')/ICMP(type=8)/Raw(load='UZe5ICdH'),fragsize=2),timeout=1,iface="wlp2s0")
```